# Difference between a range of dates to dates already registered

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date

I need an way of to calculate the difference of a range of dates to other dates already persisted in database, i.e.:

As arguments I would like to inform something like:

```
from 15/JAN/2013 to 27/JAN/2013
```

In database/collection I have:

```
START_DATE, END_DATE
-------------------------------------------
01/JAN/2013 00:00:00, 17/JAN/2013 22:30:00
23/JAN/2013 17:00:00, 31/JAN/2013 23:59:00
```

And the return must be:

```
17/JAN/2013 22:30:01, 23/JAN/2013 16:59:59
```

**REASON:
I have files that contains up to 40 thousand rows in range of dates. Files that intersect between dates contains the same data. This is why I need to insert only data in date range gaps.**

Thanks to everyone that could help me!

Answer (score 1):

```
select start_gap, end_gap
from(
  select 
     end_date start_gap, 
     lead(start_date) over (order by start_date) as end_gap
  from your_table
)
where end_gap is not null; --last line is not interesting
```

Comment: This may sometimes return gaps that are not there (in the case for example where there is a large interval overlap). This is because you can't "order" overlapping interval.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat sure. I assume only gaps, not overlaps. The question isn't fully specified.

Comment: What if there is no rows or only one row in the interval ? :)

Comment: this is ok, there would be no gaps.

Comment: However, reading the question again seems that user want the intersetion between his custom interval and the intervals in DB. I'm not sure what he wants. Maybe gaps helps him.

Comment: The goal is to find the "range of dates that are not registered". If there is no row, you could consider that the whole interval *is* unregistered. I understand that the question may be not fully well-specified, I was only pointing that your answer also makes (unspecified) assumptions.

Comment: @FlorinGhita you are right, I need to insert data only in the gaps. I have files that contains up to 40 thousand rows in range of dates. Files that intersect between dates contains the same data. This is why I need to insert only data in date range gaps.

Comment: So, you have lines with intersecting intervals? The query will report wrong gaps. You should provide some test scenarios. Only two rows is too few. And what you want to insert?

Comment: Ok @FlorinGhita I will arrange some test scenarios and post them soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear. Use Between operator: where dates between 15/JAN/2013 and 27/JAN/2013. And you will get exactly what is in your return.

Comment: Hi @Art! I have files that contains up to 40 thousand rows in range of dates. Files that intersect between dates contains the same data. Then this is why I need to insert only data in date range gaps.

Comment: @Marcelo Juventino-sorry, still not clear to me. Need to see real data to be able to help you. Need to know how do you insert data from files etc... Not sure what means "Files that intersect between dates contains the same data"...

Comment: I will arrange some test scenarios and post them soon. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select START_DATE,END_DATE from tablename where START_DATE>max(START_DATE) and END_DATE<max(END_DATE)
```

Comment: This will return only the NUMBER OF DAYS between end date and start date and I need the range of dates.

Comment: There wouldn't exist `START_DATE>max(START_DATE)`. And the syntax is not valid(and end_date _what_).